# Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API). Can a document inserted with IndexingDirective.Exclude be indexed afterwards?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a tool written in C# to move data to Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API). Since this tool performs bulk inserts to the target containers, I don't want the inserted items to be indexed. But I do want them to be included in the index once the migration is finished.

I'm using `IndexingDirective` property while inserting. Something like:

```
var requestOptions = new ItemRequestOptions()
{
   IndexingDirective = IndexingDirective.Exclude
};
```

Checking the [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-document), looks like that would insert an item without indexing it. But the only information in the docs says: *The acceptable value is Include or Exclude. Exclude omits the document from indexing.*

I couldn't find any doc or example explaining how to properly use this property and what happens with an item inserted using `IndexingDirective.Exclude`. Will it be excluded from indexing forever? Can it be indexed afterwards? How?

Comment: As I said in my comment below, it helped me to understand better what happens with an item inserted and not added to the index. But what I needed to know is how to rebuild the index once a bulk insert finishes, including in the index all the inserted items. Using `ReplaceDocumentAsync` to add items to the index one by one is not different to add them to the index when they are inserted.

Comment: Can you mark below response as an answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/blob/master/samples/code-samples/IndexManagement/Program.cs#L123-L162) is the sample for testing it's working. The answer is that it will be excluded from indexing forever.

*If you query for that document, you will NOT find it, because you excluded it from the index*

***BUT, the document is there and doing a `ReadDocument` by Id will prove it***:

```
/// <summary>
        /// The default index policy on a DocumentCollection will AUTOMATICALLY index ALL documents added.
        /// There may be scenarios where you want to exclude a specific doc from the index even though all other 
        /// documents are being indexed automatically. 
        /// This method demonstrates how to use an index directive to control this
        /// </summary>
        private static async Task ExplicitlyExcludeFromIndex()
        {            
            var databaseUri = UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseId);
            string collectionId = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}-ExplicitlyExcludeFromIndex", collectionIdPrefix);
            var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
            
            Console.WriteLine("\n1. Exclude a document completely from the Index");
            
            // Create a collection with default index policy (i.e. automatic = true)
            DocumentCollection collection = await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(databaseUri, new DocumentCollection { Id = collectionId });
            Console.WriteLine("Collection {0} created with index policy \n{1}", collection.Id, collection.IndexingPolicy);

            // Create a document
            // Then query on it immediately
            // Will work as this Collection is set to automatically index everything
            Document created = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionUri, new { id = "doc1", orderId = "order1" } );
            Console.WriteLine("\nDocument created: \n{0}", created);

            bool found = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri, "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.orderId='order1'").AsEnumerable().Any();
            Console.WriteLine("Document found by query: {0}", found);

            // Now, create a document but this time explictly exclude it from the collection using IndexingDirective
            // Then query for that document
            // Shoud NOT find it, because we excluded it from the index
            // BUT, the document is there and doing a ReadDocument by Id will prove it
            created = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionUri, new { id = "doc2", orderId = "order2" }, new RequestOptions
            {
                IndexingDirective = IndexingDirective.Exclude
            });
            Console.WriteLine("\nDocument created: \n{0}", created);

            found = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri, "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.orderId='order2'").AsEnumerable().Any();
            Console.WriteLine("Document found by query: {0}", found);

            Document document = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(created.SelfLink);
            Console.WriteLine("Document read by id: {0}", document!=null);
            
            // Cleanup
            await client.DeleteDocumentCollectionAsync(collectionUri);
        }
```

You can update this property using [ReplaceDocumentAsync(Document, RequestOptions, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.replacedocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_ReplaceDocumentAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Document_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

Comment: Ok, thanks @singhh-msft. That threw some light about the expected behaviour. 
Instead of having to update all the inserted items one by one to be indexed, I'd like to run a index transformation so the index is recreated for the whole container, once I finish with a batch of bulk inserts. Any idea how I can trigger that index recreation?

Comment: With all the data currently in containers, you cannot change index directly. So, this is not possible to achieve. If the above answer addresses your original query, pls mark it as an answer to help community.